# Send current gps coordinates to mySQL database using google maps api

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am trying to build a golf app in jquery where I can send the current gps coordinates to a mySQL database using a button.

The problem is that I am new to php and I am trying to find code that i can use.
I have built a database:

1. ID   int 3 autoincrement
2. LAT   float 10
3. LON   float 10

Can someone please help with some html and php code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h5>
                Play 9 holes
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

 function showPosition(position)
  {
  var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;

  var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
   +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false";
   document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"' />";
   }

 function showError(error)
  {
   switch(error.code) 
     {
   case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
       break;
     case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
       x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
        break;
     case error.TIMEOUT:
       x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
        break;
     case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
         x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
       break;
     }
   }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this code shows current location but there has to be a request function that can send position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude to database?

Comment: if you want some one to write it for you - hire them; if not at least make an effort.

Comment: What does HTML have to do with this problem?  What specifically are you having trouble with?  Do you not know how to find the current GPS coordinates?  Do you not know how to do an AJAX request to send the data?  Can you not handle the data on the PHP side?  Do you not know how to write a MySQL INSERT query?  Be specific as to what the problem is.

Comment: Don't know how a bunch of latitude/longitudes are going to be of use to you. That's like saying you've got a bunch of street numbers, but no street name/city/state

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do, but here's some articles in the Google Maps API site on using PHP and MySQL with the Google Maps API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode

Comment: what I am trying to do is store current location at the 'tee' of the course then walk to the next shot and then pick up them coordinates, then I can measure the distance. but first of all i need to collec the data.   @brad thanks for the quick response, i know how to do a mysql insert using a form and i can get google maps to show the current coordinates. i do not know how to use AJAX request?

Comment: most of the code i have found doesnt populate the database on button click with the current coordinates, rather it just inputs from a text box by typing it in.(i need button onclick....latitude and longitude....into mysql database

Comment: Did you review these articles?

Comment: yes thank you, i have read these articles before and been trying to use google code playground with not much success. where these articles show the current location, populating the database they do not show automatic data to database

Comment: I don't have time for a longer post but you want an onclick event for your button that sends data to the database in a post, much like you did with form data.