# Store google maps lat and lng to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have the following javascript.

```
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src=geo.js></script>
<script>
      function onPositionUpdate(position)
        {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            document.write("Current position: " + lat + " " + lng);


        }


          </script>
```

I want to upload the results to my database.
Column layout

ID   |   Lat   |   LNG   |   URL

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: ive tried using GET and POST to another page and then uplaod but thats not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use server side language (e.g. PHP ) and send this data with ajax request

Comment: I have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095983/send-current-gps-coordinates-to-mysql-database-using-google-maps-api

Comment: @davemorin the link you posted shows `client-side` (JS) not `server-side`

Comment: I guess i really dont know what im doing here LOL... I want to track users locations that allow my app but cannot figure it out.  Its a weather app and want to track most popular locations

Comment: If anyone else is interested in doing this.. This is how i did it.

Full Code: http://pastebin.com/DCgYfukW

Added this:

    document.getElementById("coord").value = ("" + lat + "," + lng);

This form:

    <form method="GET" action="test.php">
 <input id="coord" name="coord" value="">
 <input type="submit" value="Enter Location">
    </form>

And my PHP:

    $weather_loc = $_GET["coord"];
    //echo $weather_loc;

Comment: and ofcourse the database stuff but i dont think i need to explain that